# Maximum load of search entries block

Tags: search, blocks

Is there a way to block a user, when he constant enter a search query?
I mean in a inhuman kind of way (say 10 hits per sec).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use firewall or cache or,

nginx

```
http {
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=search:25m rate=1r/s;  


server { 
location ~* /catalogsearch/ {
        limit_req zone=search burst=2;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;
        }
```